# There're Stack Overflow, Server Fault, and more -- where should I ask my question?

Tags: discussion, questions

I am a fan of Stack Overflow, and I see that SO has many sister sites, like Server Fault, etc. I really appreciate them, but their names need to give hints about what each site is all about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't the names already do that?

- A **Stack Overflow** is an error made while programming; SO is for programming questions
- **Server Fault** has "server" right in the name; SF is for server administration questions
- A **Super User** is a user with above-average capabilities on a computer; SU is for general computer software/hardware questions

As [user118150 said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66083/theres-stackoverflow-serverfault-and-more-where-should-i-ask-my-question/66084#66084), the FAQ of each site ([SO](https://stackoverflow.com/faq), [SF](https://serverfault.com/faq), [SU](https://superuser.com/faq)) breaks down exactly what's on-topic on that site, but the names are pretty helpful too

---

As for figuring out where you should ask a question, if you're still unsure you can post a description of the question here and we'll help you figure it out; beyond the trilogy sites there are [24 public SE betas](https://stackexchange.com/sites) that your question might work on too

Comment: Super User really doesn't make that much sense though till you read what its about...

Answer (score 5):

Consider looking at the master list of sites:

https://stackexchange.com/sites

It lists all the sites and descriptions on one nice page.

Answer (score 3):

Reading the FAQs of the various sites should be helpful in figuring that out. The three main sites are serverfault, superuser and stackoverflow. There is a stackexchange process for making more sites in the future, but that process is currently under development.