# Finding the right SE site for a problem

Tags: feature-request, site-recommendation, stack-exchange

I am not sure how to make a suggestion. I will position the problem and then a solution/idea. Even if my idea would be adopted there may still be a problem, but I am just trying to close the gap.

**Problem:**

As a new user it is not obvious how to use SE. As an intermediate user it is not obvious which site to use in each situation, and also probably the same for even an advanced user, somewhat of an impossible problem to solve. Sure photography/physics/math to name a few are easy to find which site to use.

My issue was in Office 365 & OneDrive, there is no 365/MS/OneDrive SE.
So I came to this link.
https://stackexchange.com/sites#
and found all sites, and this did not offer me any help for my Office 365 OneDrive issue.

**Ideas:**

1. When hovering over a site load a word cloud of the site tags inside the site (bubble).
2. Make the tags searchable, filterable, to help find the site which uses that word the most.

This way the punters can find a good site, easier, when trying to be diligent SE users.

However I just searched for these tags:

- "office365" SO=7k tags used, and SU=1k
- "onedrive" SO=2.5k, SU=750

This would suggest SO would be my best place to ask my question, however I got told to take my question to SU.
So maybe my theory is wrong, maybe SO is naturally higher because of the larger usergroup?

My question: Was this the right content to post here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where do I ask where to ask?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168103/where-do-i-ask-where-to-ask)

Comment: I believe this is a feature request, which would make it not a duplicate of that.

Answer (score 8):

> when hovering over a site load a word cloud of the site tags inside the site (bubble).

Would this really help more than searching for tags? Just some numbers I got from looking at the tags pages on three sites: SO has ~64.3k tags, SU has ~6.4k tags, even a 'small' site like Interpersonal Skills has almost 300 tags. There's no way you can show all of those in a bubble of tags, and still clearly convey *what* a site is about.

For example, Stack Overflow has a [java](/questions/tagged/java) tag. But questions about [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java) would be off-topic. A tag alone does not convey the topic of a site.

> Make the tags searchable, filterable, to help find the site which uses that word the most.

I also don't think this would help. After all, you manually did the same and still picked the 'wrong' site. I wrote a bit about thist [before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/329380/369802): The number of questions in a tag doesn't say much about the site's suitability for your question, without taking into account the size of site it's on, and without taking into account the actual *topic* of the site.

SO may indeed have more questions in a tag just because there are more questions on SO in general. That doesn't mean everything that could be tagged with such a tag would automatically be on-topic on SO.

While word clouds with relation to a site are a nice idea (they can give more information about a site's topic than  "Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers" or "Q&A for computer enthusiasts and power users" does), they should be based on more than just the tags used on a site.

Comment: This is a really good explaination of why what I was suggesting would not help and was the conclusion I was drawing.
Cheers

Comment: I just used the suggested searches SuperUser 9 : 5 StackOverflow.
From there best to read the description of the site.

 - In my defence - I assumed Stack Overflow was the "Overflow" of all other sites and hence when I saw a ton of 365 questions it confirmed my assumption.
wont do that again :)

Answer (score 3):

One way of implementing this in accordance with what you are asking, (but without making a lot of modifications), is to add a new **Search Bar** to the Stack Exchange main [All Sites - Grid View](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=grid):

> [image: Modified - All Sites - Grid View]

That webpage normally displays different sized site logos based on the site's size.

It wouldn't be too difficult to resize the logos based on the number of search hits returned; giving an indication of the site's popularity for a given search.

You could tap/mouseover on one of the sites to see what sort of results were being returned, and possibly tweak the terms used, to narrow down the search and redisplay the icon cloud:

> [image: Grid Cloud on Mouseover]

Comment: This would be good. the other answer says it is not a good indication.
so maybe tweak it a little, maybe the size should be based on proportion of that tag on the site. Bigger the percentage the bigger the icon.
even then in my example office365 still does not fit StackOverflow unless you a coding a 365 solution.

Comment: @NZDev, the other answers was written before mine and hasn't been edited. What you suggest as an improving tweak [in your comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361073/finding-the-right-se-site-for-a-problem/361091?noredirect=1#comment1204933_361091) is already mentioned in the third sentence of my answer.

Comment: No the point you did not refer to which the other answer does refer to is: number of results popularity does not mean best site for the question.
What I said (badly) was divide the number of results by the size of the site to get a portion of the site, then order the sites by that number.

Another addon solution could be to provide the various sites roles "AppDev/AppSupport/..." and by selecting the role points the user at the appropriate site/s.